# Google Play Services aar download for above 11.0.4

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

**From where to download the google-play-services aar files for version 11.6.0 OR above 11.0.4**

I know just by adding the dependency in apps `build.gradle` adds the library in it.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
```

This is fair in case of Android Studio.

But as a **Unity Developer**, I have downloaded the [Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/3.9.0) which after import gives the play services *ads, lite, basement, gass* of version 11.6.0

Now we have some **location** dependency in our project. So I have downloaded the Android SDK and its stored in this path.

`/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`

After navigating to `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms`,

I got the latest play services library of version **11.0.4** only and if I tried to create a Android Studio project by adding GPS dependency of 11.6.0, its getting added properly.

So my question is,

**where google play services library of version 11.6.0 is downloaded. So that I can go to that location and get all the aar file needed for my Unity Project**

Comment: Any update on this, as its very important for me to understand, so that I can continue in Unity game development with GPS location library of version 11.6.0

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following are the details from Android developer documentation:

**Programmatic access:**

For programmatic access to Google's Maven artifacts, you can get an XML list of artifact groups from *maven.google.com/master-index.xml* ([link](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/master-index.xml)) which gives the **group path**

Then, for any group, you can view its library names and versions at:

*maven.google.com/group_path/group-index.xml*

For example, libraries in the *`android.arch.lifecycle`* group are listed at *maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/group-index.xml* ([link](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/group-index.xml)).

You can also download the POM and JAR files at:
*maven.google.com/group_path/library/version/library-version.ext*

For example:

*maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom.* ([link](https://maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/compiler/1.0.0/compiler-1.0.0.pom))

For more details please refer: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#gmaven-access

For complete list of Google Play Services libraries, refer below xml:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/group-index.xml

Eg: To download Google Play Services Location library AAR file, use the following link:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.0/play-services-location-11.6.0.aar

You can replace group name, version, file, extension to download other files.

Note: Do check the pom file for each module, it may have dependencies on other Google Play Services libraries. If so, you will need to download all dependent files.

**[Update]:**

**You can use Google's Unity Jar Resolver for this:**

https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Answer (score 1):

Check the links below:

[play-services-ads-11.6.0](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.6.0/play-services-ads-11.6.0.aar)

[play-services-location-11.6.0](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.0/play-services-location-11.6.0.aar)

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I need to get all the play services libraries. Can you help me from where you got this link? This help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can find and download all versions of the aar libraries at the [MVN repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms).

Also:

I came across a github project for Titanium/Appcelerator/AxWay. It has a script that downloads the latest play-services libraries.

The project is at: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.playservices

The relevant script is: updater/index.js

Hopefully the script will not go away because it is very useful.